# TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When i click on save appears the question title error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined". i am copying the html and the controller js

When i click on save appears the question title error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined". i am copying the html and the controller js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <title>.: IceDreamApp :.</title>
  <body ng-controller="sueniosLista">
                <h1>Lista de sueños</h1>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="suenio-item" ng-repeat="suenio in suenios">
                        <div class="nombre"> {{suenio.nombre}} - {{suenio.suenioDescription}}</div>
                        <span class="estadoAnimo"> {{suenio.animo}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="wrapper">
                    <h2>Añadir sueño</h2>
                    Nombre: <input type="text" ng-model="sueniosLista.nombre"></input>
                    Que soñaste?: <input type="text" ng-model="sueniosLista.suenioDescription"></input>
                    Cual fue tu estado de ánimo?: <input type="text" ng-model="sueniosLista.animo"></input>
                    <button ng-click="Save()">Guardar</button>
                </div>
      <script src="angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>

function sueniosLista ($scope){
    $scope.suenios= [
        {nombre: "Daniel Galan Romano", suenioDescription: "Soñe que me comia un tiburon que estaba re loco porque no sabia que mierda hacer porque estaba solo en altamar", animo: "miedoso"},{nombre: "Dante", suenioDescription: "Soñe que me comia un tiburon que estaba re loco porque no sabia que mierda hacer porque estaba solo en altamar", animo: "miedoso"}


    ];

    $scope.Save=function(){

        $scope.suenios.push({nombre:$scope.nuevoSuenio.nombre, suenioDescription:$scope.nuevoSuenio.suenioDescription, animo:$scope.nuevoSuenio.animo })
    }

}
```

Comment: well `$scope.nuevoSuenio` is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your save function there is this line:

```
$scope.suenios.push({
    nombre: $scope.nuevoSuenio.nombre,
    suenioDescription: $scope.nuevoSuenio.suenioDescription,
    animo: $scope.nuevoSuenio.animo
});
```

There is no `nuevoSuenio` defined in your code as model. I think you should change that to `sueniosLista`, like:

```
$scope.suenios.push({
    nombre: $scope.sueniosLista.nombre,
    suenioDescription: $scope.sueniosLista.suenioDescription,
    animo: $scope.sueniosLista.animo
});
```